# Inspect URL hash to find section and page using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a URL like: `domain.com/#/section-1/page-2/`

I want to inspect it to find out what the section and page number is.

I've tried:

```
var currentSection = 0;
var currentPage = 0;

if( window.location.hash != '' ) {

    currentSection = window.location.hash.match('[section-/]');

    currentPage = window.location.hash.match('[page-/]');

}
```

But my regex is rather poor. How would I get the info I want? I want JUST the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simple regex on `location.href` plus some mapping:

```
var nums = location.href.match(/(section|page)-\d+/g).map(
    function(x){ return +x.replace(/\D/g,"") }
);
```

`nums[0]` will give section number.

`nums[1]` will give page number.

Comment: How do I get the numbers from that? I don't follow? Thanks :)

Comment: @Cameron wait a minute!

Comment: @Cameron glad to have helped you :)